# Is there any Text-Plugins for the WebStorm to highlight the Cucumber Scenario comment line from the scenario's steps?

Tags: javascript, plugins, cucumber, webstorm, highlight

[image: Cucumber feature file SS]

As you see from the scenarios when I move the `#` from the second scenario the comment line becomes white color as scenario steps. I don't want to use `#` sign but still be able to highlight/differentiate comment line from the rest of steps with different color. Do you know any text-plugins that can do that with WebStorm IDE? Thank you very much in advance.